# jquery .each iterating

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, checkboxlist

I am new to learning jquery so my apologies if this is a relatively easy question.
I have an asp.net checkboxlist with an ID of ChartstoDisplay. I am trying to create jquery to toggle the style back and forth dependent on whether an individual list item checkbox is checked. The code i have is below, the style 'selected' should be changed the checkboxes that are checked to bold green text but nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChartstoDisplay').click(function () {
            $('input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

My understanding is that the 'input'.each is iterating through the items in the checkbox list looking for input tags, then the next line, using the this variable, checks for whether or not the checkbox is checked, if so it should be changing it's style.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? it should work

Comment: It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Tcsww/4/

Comment: Perhaps what you want is to have class toggling when individual checkbox is clicked, not when the whole group is clicked? I.e. I check checkbox A - its style changes... I uncheck it - its style changes... without altering all other elements... is that it?

Comment: yes jakub, thats the idea, who to implement?

Comment: Look at the end of Amadan's reply - after "what I think you wanted is.." - basically you say "when someone *clicks* a "checkbox" which is under #xxxxx in DOM tree, do xxxx on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something else, because your code seems to be valid, just couple of best practices:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChartstoDisplay').click(function () {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).toggleClass("selected");
        });
     });
</script>
```

- Don't select all the `input`s, select only checkboxes.
- Select only checkboxes under the clicked list.
- Use the `:checked` selector to remove the filtering checks.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/zBB6g/)

Comment: I tried shyju's fiddle, it didnt change the style color...is it a css problem      here is the css  'code'.selected
{
    color: darkgreen;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: Checkboxes don't have fonts. They're just a box with a checkmark. If you want to change the color of the label corresponding to the box, it's a very different story.

Comment: @dinotom. Added a fiddle, check it out.

Comment: @Amadan, that is what im trying to change the label associated with the individual checkbox

Comment: gdoron, I see that your form works but im using asp.net where the checkboxlist items text value is the text of an asp.net listitem and the html is in the "label" attribute under the checkbox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11284/discussion-between-dinotom-and-gdoron)

Answer (score 1):

It works. It probably doesn't do what you want, though. First of all, can you show us what CSS you have attached to `.selected`?

What this does is, it will toggle all the currently checked boxes. Let's say you have boxes A, B and C.

- Click on A. Box A is checked. Box A gets toggled. Selected is only A.
- Click on B. Box A and B are checked. Both get toggled. Selected is only B.
- Click on C. Box A, B and C are checked. All of them get toggled. A and C are now selected.
- Click on B, unchecking it. A and C are checked, and they get toggled (but not B). Nothing remains selected.

If this is what you want, great, but I can't think of a single application where this odd behaviour would be  required.

What I think you wanted is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ChartstoDisplay').on("click", "input:checkbox", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
});​
```

**EDIT:** Given the code OP provided in the fiddle, here's the updated answer ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77Mub/1/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ChartstoDisplay').on("click", "input:checkbox", function() {
        $(this).next().toggleClass("selected");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Amadan, there are five check boxes. What i am trying to accomplish is to have any "checked" boxes style changed from the default style to a new style, a bolded green font and back to the default when it is unchecked

Comment: here is the css class 'code'.selected
{
    color: darkgreen;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: As I said, checkboxes don't have fonts. What is your HTML for the checckboxes? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pgeWa/)'s an example; notice `.parent()` being inserted. If your HTML is different, the code will be different as well. If you post your HTML structure, I'll copy this information to the answer from the fiddle.

Comment: here is the link to the fiddle im working on which still doesnt work

Comment: Amadan...im assuming you sent me something re"Here you go"...I dont see a link and the jsfiddle i created is unchanged. Can you resend what you sent?

Comment: @dinotom: I edited my answer with a big honking **EDIT**, including a new fiddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11364/discussion-between-dinotom-and-amadan)

Answer (score 0):

The `$('input').each(...)` is iterating through *all* inputs on the page, not just checkboxes and not just the ones that belong to "#ChartstoDisplay". For each one that is checked it should successfully toggle the class - I don't see anything in your code that would stop that working, so perhaps you could show your html?

You can simplify your code though, to:

```
$('input:checked').toggleClass('selected');
```

This will toggle the class of all matching elements - no need to iterate through them with `.each()`.

Or to just do inputs within "#ChartstoDisplay", which is closer to what you really want to do:

```
$('input:checked', this).toggleClass('selected');
```

Where passing a second parameter to the `$()` function only selects elements in the context of that second parameter - I'm passing `this` since at that point `this` would be "#ChartstoDisplay" given that that line of code is inside the "#ChartstoDisplay" click event handler.